# Undefined webrat methods in cucumber step_definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, webrat

When i run my features i get this error:

```
undefined method `visit' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x81b17ac0> (NoMethodError)
```

This is the relevant part of my `Gemfile`.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0.beta.19"
  gem "cucumber"
  gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 0.3.2"
  gem 'webrat', ">= 0.7.2.beta.1"
end
```

The relating step_definition (though i don't think it's important)

```
When /^I create a movie Caddyshack in the Comendy genre$/ do
  visit movies_path
  click_link "Add Movie"
  fill_in "Title", :with => "Caddyshack"
  check "Comedy"
  click_button "Save"
end
```

In the env.rb i have the following Webrat configuration:

```
# […]
require 'webrat'
require 'webrat/core/matchers'

Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :rails
  config.open_error_files = false # Set to true if you want error pages to pop up in the browser
end
# […]
```

Anything i am missing here?

Comment: Wow… since i just got a popular questions badge for this one it seems to me this hasn't yet been patched. Will check that out later…

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had to set `config.mode` to `:rack` instead of `:rails`:

```
# […]
require 'webrat'
require 'webrat/core/matchers'

Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :rack
  config.open_error_files = false # Set to true if you want error pages to pop up in the browser
end
# […]
```

now works as expected.

Comment: In case people don't know this is to be edited in features/support/env.rb

Comment: This solution worked for me...  However, why is it required?  I would think that the rails generator should generate the correct thing, whether that's a mode of :rails (which the [webrat readme](https://github.com/brynary/webrat#readme) seems to say is the right thing, by the way) or of :rack... But this seems not to be the case.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: Thx you so much, it was such an annoying issue.

Comment: I've run into this, but when I change the webrat method to :rack instead of :rails, all the response.should be_success tests fail. Everyone one of them with this: undefined method `success?' for #<Rack::MockResponse:00000000000000> (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1):

Paul Nelligan try adding this to env.rb to fix the error : **"no such file to load -- action_controller/integration"**

```
World(Webrat::Methods)
World(Webrat::Matchers)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error on two separate occasions: the first instance the adjustment to confg.mode solved the problem; the second time, however, after a lot of frustration I found a link that suggested a buggy version of bundler could be the culprit. Updating it solved the problem.