# Undefined Webrat methods in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

When I set up a new rails 3.1.3 project and write a Cucumber story with Webrat code, like this:

```
response.should contain("abc")
```

and I run `rake cucumber`, I get:

```
undefined method `contain' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x00000003d2c578> (NoMethodError)
```

I believe that either Cucumber or Webrat or Rails is broken because I did nothing special at all and stuck to documentation.

The following steps reproduce the error:

- `rvm 1.9.2`
- `rails new testapp -d mysql`
- `cd testapp`
- {{ Edit database.yml }}
- `rake db:create`
- `rake db:migrate`
- `gem install cucumber-rails`
- `gem install webrat`
- `gem install database_cleaner`
- {{ Edit Gemfile to include 'cucumber-rails', 'webrat' and 'database_cleaner' without version numbers }}
- `bundle install`
- `rails g cucumber:install`
- `rails g controller genres index`
- add "resources :genres" to routes.rb
- {{ rails s and http://localhost:3000/genres works now }}
- Create /features/create_movie.feature with contents:

`Feature: Create movie`

```
Description

  Scenario: Create a movie in genre
    Given a genre named Comedy
    When I create a movie Caddyshack in the Comedy genre
    Then Caddyshack should be in the Comedy genre
```

- Create /features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb with contents:

`Given /^a genre named Comedy$/ do
    end`

```
When /^I create a movie Caddyshack in the Comedy genre$/ do
end

Then /^Caddyshack should be in the Comedy genre$/ do
  visit genres_path
  response.should contain("abc")
end
```

- `rake cucumber`
- It fails with the error quoted above.
- Various suggestions in the internet did NOT work (e.g. [Undefined webrat methods in cucumber step_definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546011/undefined-webrat-methods-in-cucumber-step-definitions))
- My versions:

rails 3.1.3
cucumber 1.1.4
cucumber-rails 1.2.1
webrat 0.7.3
rack 1.3.5
rake 0.9.2.2

Any hints about how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Now by default Cucumber use Capybary instead of Webrat .

You need use have_content instead.

Correct snippet below:

```
When /^I create a movie Caddyshack in the Comedy genre$/ do
end

Then /^Caddyshack should be in the Comedy genre$/ do
  visit genres_path
  response.should have_content("abc")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just received a response from the Cucumber (cukes) Google group:

> Cucumber-Rails dropped support for Webrat in v0.5.0.beta1 (See
>   https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/master/History.md)
>
> Use Capybara instead.